# razor MVC EF how to show and hide a div based on model condition

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Total noob here :) 
I have simple form on my index.cshtml that submits values to m y controller and which also displays the results. I would like this form to be hidden @if (Model != null). It looks like this:

```html
<div id="inputform" class="visible">
    <form id="certlookup" class="form-inline" role="form" method="get">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div><input class="form-control" name="prefix" placeholder="99" maxlength="2" type="number" required /></div>
            <div><select class="form-control dropdown" name="type" id="type"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select></div>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" name="suffix" placeholder="9999" maxlength="4" type="number" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Go!" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@if (Model != null)
{...}
```

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I tried to set a variable after my Model != null statement, setting the class=@hidden, but that variable wasn't available in the form above.

Is this going to be possible? This is for a mobile first site so I'd like the form input to go away after the results are provided but ideally I don't want to use a separate page for form and results. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just check if Model is null before the form:

```
@if (Model == null)
{
<div id="inputform" class="visible">
    <form id="certlookup" class="form-inline" role="form" method="get">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div><input class="form-control" name="prefix" placeholder="99" maxlength="2" type="number" required /></div>
            <div><select class="form-control dropdown" name="type" id="type"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select></div>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" name="suffix" placeholder="9999" maxlength="4" type="number" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Go!" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
}
```

Or maybe set the class in the "inputformdiv":

```
@{
   string cssClass = Model == null ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
<div id="inputform" class="@cssClass">
<form id="certlookup" class="form-inline" role="form" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div><input class="form-control" name="prefix" placeholder="99" maxlength="2" type="number" required /></div>
        <div><select class="form-control dropdown" name="type" id="type"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select></div>
        <div>
            <input class="form-control" name="suffix" placeholder="9999" maxlength="4" type="number" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Go!" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Stefano! I made a small tweak to your second recommended way: Model.Count() == 0 ? "visible" : "hidden"; and it works as desired! Thank you!

Comment: How can I do the same thing but using partial views and Html.RenderAction. The partial view renders no matter what the if condition is

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition in MVC view  with `FirstOrDefault()` or without

this was solved my issue :

```
@if (Model.Table_Name.FirstOrDefault().Column_Name.HasValue == true)

<div>

// your code 

</div>
```